# Unsupported lookup 'slug' for CharField or join on the field not permitted - Usando campos slugs en un queryset (Django 1.9)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Estoy trabajando con [la vista basada en clase (CBV) ListView](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.9/django.views.generic.list/ListView/), la cual lo que hace es retornar una lista de objetos en donde puedo hacer:

**1.** Si uso `ListView` sin cambiar su clase ni hacerle nada me retorna una lista de por ejemplo todos los objetos de un modelo sin mayor esfuerzo la verdad, para lo cual necesitamos solamente darle el modelo y el template a renderizar.

**2.** Puedo utilizar su método `get_queryset()` para decirle que me filtre por un atributo determinado o para ejecutar una consulta personalizada para que me devuelva objetos específicos acorde al criterio del queryset dado.

Estoy utilizando `ListView` para recuperar la lista de usuarios del modelo User el cual es un modelo personalizado que está en una aplicación creada llamada userprofile.

```
# settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
        ...
    'userprofile',
        ...
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'userprofile.User'
```

En el modelo User en models.py estoy adicionando unos atributos especiales, entre ellos un campo llamado `slug`, para poder consultar los datos de un usuario específico.

Un slug es parte de un url que hace más amigablemente posible la lectura de la misma para los humanos. Ayuda mucho al SEO.

```
# userprofile/models.py
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_medical = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_physiotherapist = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_patient=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    #slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'

class MedicalProfile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class PatientProfile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class PhysiotherapistProfile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Por el momento, mi ListView para consultar el listado de usuarios lo he llamado UserListView y es este:

```
# userprofile/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import  User
#from django.http import JsonResponse

class UserListView(ListView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'user_list.html'
```

Mi template user_list.html  recibe un `object_list` de parte de la vista y con un ciclo recorre los objetos del modelo. Si dicho `object_list` llega vacío, va al tag empty y notifica que no hay objetos (usuarios) aún para mostrar

```
# userprofile/templates/user_list.html
{% block content %}
    <h1>Users</h1>
    <div>
        {% for users in object_list %}
        <div>
            {{ users.username }}
            {{ users.password }}
            {{ users.first_name }}
            {{ users.last_name }}
            {{ users.photo }}
            {{ users.email }}
            {{ users.slug }}
            <br />
        </div>
        {% empty %}
            <div>No hay usuarios todavia</div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

En mi archivo de userprofiles/urls.py tengo mi url que llama a la vista `UserListView` de esta forma:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
from .views import UserListView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^users/$', UserListView.as_view(), name='users_list'),
]
```

Es entonces, como cuando accedo al url `http://localhost:8000/users/`obtengo un listado de las instancias del modelo User, es decir mis usuarios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta aqui todo funciona bien y quería incluir este proceso, para mostrar lo que deseo hacer ahora y es donde esta mi problema:

Quiero cambiar el comportamiento del queryset de la cbv `[ListView][1]` es decir sobreescribir el metodo `get_queryset()` o la segunda opción de la que hablaba al principio.

Lo que quiero básicamente es que esta vista de UserListView, que ya me devuelve mi lista de usuarios, si yo le paso en el url el nombre de un usuario en especial, me traiga solamente los datos de un usuario. Por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este ejemplo no esta funcionando, solo fue adaptado para efectos de ilustración.

Es entonces cuando entra en juego el campo slug que adicione en el modelo User en userprofile/models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_medical = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_physiotherapist = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_patient=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    #slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars')
```

Entonces si lo que quiero es traerme solo los datos de un usuario o instancia en especial, debo cambiar el método get_queryset() para que se comporte acorde a mis necesidades.

Lo sobreescribo en la lista UserListView creada en userprofile/wiews.py

- Primero adiciono un nuevo url que reciba el nombre de ese usuario. Este url se llamara users y recibe una expresión regular en donde le digo que el usuario que va a recibir (la palabra `username`) será parte de la expresión regular:

Y también le digo que esa expresión regular permita caracteres alfanuméricos (con el w) tanto minúsculas como mayúsculas y que permita guiones altos y que puedan estar muchas veces. Esta expresión regular en este url se llama `username` y apunta a la vista `UserListView`

```
# userprofile/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
from .views import LogoutView, UserListView
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^users/$', UserListView.as_view(), name='users_list'),
    url(r'^users/(?P<username>[\w\-]+)/$', UserListView.as_view(), name='users_list'),

]
```

es el nombre del usuario que le enviaremos en el url

- Sobreescribiendo el get_queryset()

Es entonces como en la vista UserListView sobreescribo el método `get_queryset()`

> En las Class Based Views, todos los parámetros de url y de parámetros extras que yo le envíe a una vista todos llegan a una variable que se llama kwargs

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if self.kwargs
```

Entonces, pregunto que si dentro de esos `kwargs` tengo al username que está en el url, si existe el username, entonces que me retorne los datos de ese username solamente  y sino, que actúe como el query_set original de la vista basada en clase ListView, como antes de que empezara a sobreescribirlo:

Nótese que en el queryset, estoy indicando, que busque por el slug del usuario o del modelo User, que es `username` (Aunque acá tengo la duda de si esto esta bien planteado dado el error que mostraré un poco mas adelante)

En el queryset planteado, quiero decir:
Que me retorne todos los datos en donde el slug del usuario sea el que le llego por el url. Es decir el `username`

Y si no trae el slug con algun nombre de un usuario existente, sino solo http://localhost:8000/users/ entonces que me retorne todos los usuarios del modelo User, que es como lo tengo en un principio y me funciona, dado que es el comportamiento normal del método get_queryset() de la cbv `ListView`. Para eso utilizo el super, para llamar al padre de UserListView que es ListView y se llama específicamente a la funcion get_queryset() original.

```
def get_queryset(self):
        if self.kwargs.get('username'):
            #Devolver datos de usuario definimos un queryset para ello
            queryset = self.model.objects.filter(username__slug=self.kwargs['username'])
        else:
            #Actue igual que siempre el queryset
            queryset = super(UserListView, self).get_queryset()

        return queryset
```

Es entonces cuando quiero consultar los datos de un usuario en particular y obtengo el siguiente mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es entonces como llego a mi inquietud, y para ser preciso, no estopy muy seguro acerca de  como estoy formulando el queryset específico, dado que le estoy diciendo que lo aplique al modelo User y que me filtre por el atributo username de ese modelo (es por ese atributo o asi es el nombre del slug en la expresión regular del url que planteo para esta funcionalidad), solo que tengo mis dudas en esta parte de definir el queryset.

```
queryset = self.model.objects.filter(username__slug=self.kwargs['username'])
```

¿De pronto alguien puede orientarme un poco en esta parte?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: `username__slug` no me parece que sea válido, ambos son campos del mismo modelo no tiene sentido ese lookup

Comment: Creo que tienes razón, he cometido un "Homero Simpson" por así decirlo con este tema. Lo que andaba pensando era poner el slug en los modelos Profile correspondientes (Patient, Medical, Physiotherapist), y que se basaran en el name (campo que también esta en los profiles mencionados) y hacer el lookup basado en el F.K del User en cada profile, pero creo que tu propuesta abajo está mas técnica. La probaré.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que yo haría es lo siguiente, si ese campo es nuevo asumo que existirían usuarios cuyo campo `slug` esté vació o nulo. Entonces podrías crear un `signal` al crear el usuario para que se guarde su campo `slug` basado en su `username` usando [`slugify`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#slugify):

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

from userprofile.models import User


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def post_save_user(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    slug = slugify(instance.username)
    User.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk).update(slug=slug)
```

Si decides hacer lo anterior sobreescribiendo el método `save()` del modelo entonces no funcionará para los casos en los que crees un usuario desde el admin, es por eso que es mejor usar un `signal`.

Tu `urls.py` sería algo asi:

```
# userprofile/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
from .views import LogoutView, UserListView


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^users/$', UserListView.as_view(), name='users_list'),
    url(r'^users/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', UserListView.as_view(), name='users_list'),
]
```

Y tu `get_queryset()`:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if self.kwargs.get('slug'):                
        queryset = self.model.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
    else:
        queryset = super(UserListView, self).get_queryset()
    return queryset
```

---

### Nota:

No he tenido tiempo de probarlo en mi proyecto pero estoy casi seguro que debería funcionar, me comentas.

Comment: en efecto tu solución funciona para el listado de un único usuario, pero cuando creo un usuario desde el admin de Django, ocurre este error (https://cldup.com/V7PDLxpEFH.png) En este post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222416/recursion-in-python-runtimeerror-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-while-callin) se dice que python carece de manejar de forma óptima la recursividad y esta esta limitada a 999 llamadas, pero que puede setearse en setrecursionlimit()

Comment: En este otro posts hacen algo con el limite del tamaño de la pila o stack también  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061582/setting-stacksize-in-a-python-script/16248113#16248113) pero obtuve esto cuando grabe un usuario 4748 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./manage.py runserver Y cuando creo un user por consola django, se queda en un loop, y el proceso de createsuperuser se qeuda en un Status code D+. No se que signifique eso.

Comment: @bgarcial perdoname, debi probar esto antes, no debi usar `save` dentro del signal, es por eso que entra en recursión, mejor usemos un update. Mira la actualizacion

Comment: muchas gracias, lo que no acabe de comprender del todo es que porque se daba lo del problema de recursividad ...

Comment: @bgarcial fácil, porque el signal ocurre justamente cuando se llama al metodo `save` del modelo `User`, y si dentro del signal volvemos a usar `save` entonces entra en un loop infinito

Comment: No se dice setear, se dice configurar.