# ¿Cómo trabajar con signals (post_save)?

Tags: django, django-models

Tengo un esquema de usuarios por roles (medical, patient, physiotherapist) que deriva de la clase AbstractUser para utilizarlo en los request como se ve en los siguientes modelos:

```
#models.py

from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_medical = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_physiotherapist = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', null = True, blank = True)

    def get_medical_profile(self):
        medical_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'medicalprofile'):
            medical_profile=self.medicalprofile
        return medical_profile

    def get_patient_profile(self):
        patient_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'patientprofile'):
            patient_profile = self.patientprofile
        return patient_profile

    def get_physiotherapist_profile(self):
        physiotherapist_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'physiotherapistprofile'):
            physiotherapist_profile = self.physiotherapistprofile
        return physiotherapist_profile

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'

class MedicalProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class PatientProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class PhysiotherapistProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Lo que deseo es que cuando se cree un nuevo usuario, de manera automática, se cree su perfil dependiendo de su campo si es médico, paciente, o fisioterapeuta (`is_medical`, `is_patient`, `is_physiotherapist`)

Para eso estoy utilizando el signal de `post_save()` de la siguiente manera en el mismo archivo models.py en donde estan mis modelos:

En el signal estoy enviándo tres parámetros mas el **kwargs:

- `sender`, que es mi modelo de usuarios
- `created`, un parámetro booleano que me indica que una instancia de mi modelo de usuario `AUTH_USER_MODEL`ha sido creada
- `instance`, la instancia de usuario que se está creando

Para saber que un usuario esta a punto de crearse, de alguna manera debo indagar si en ese request que hago (crear el usuario), va ese usuario o esa instancia que esta por crearse, para lo cual hago `user = self.request.user`

```
    @receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    def create_profile_for_new_user(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
        # Pregunto si en el request va el user, aqui va mi inquietud
        user = self.request.user
        #user = get_user_model()
        if created:
            if user.is_medical:
                profile=MedicalProfile(user=instance)
                profile.save()
```

Es una buena lógica, pero resulta que no he definido el self y obtengo (de manera obvia) este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el método en `create_profile_for_new_user(...)` al cual le estoy aplicando el signal de `post_save()` solo tengo cuatro atributos, por lo que si agrego self como atributo al inicio

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_profile_for_new_user(self,sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
```

obtendría este error:

```
TypeError: create_profile_for_new_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Dec/2015 22:57:04] "GET /admin/userprofile/user/add/?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Otra opción que estaba contemplando es obtener el usuario que se esta creando con la función `get_user_model()`como lo hago acá (importando previamente la función claro esta `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model`):

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    def create_profile_for_new_user(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
        # Pregunto si en el request va el user, aqui va mi inquietud
        #user = self.request.user
        user = get_user_model()
        if created:
            if user.is_medical:
                profile=MedicalProfile(user=instance)
                profile.save()
```

Pero cuando lo hago obtengo este mensaje, y es lógico, pues mi objeto User (estoy es obteniendo una instancia del modelo User original de Django) no tiene el atributo por el que pregunto, en este caso `is_medical`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acorde a lo anterior, no se como preguntar o indagar por el usuario para examinar sus atributos booleanos (`is_patient`, `is_medical`, `is_physiotherapist`) y crear su perfil respectivo acorde a ello.

De paso aprovecho y me surge otra inquietud: ¿Es posible utilizar el signal de `post_save` para más de un propósito?

En este caso, quiero utilizarlo tanto para crear un perfil de la instancia del usuario que se crea  y para darle valor a un campo llamado `slug` en base a su atributo `first_name`. Es decir ¿lo podría aplicar a los métodos que necesite?

Comment: Interesante el color que tiene tu traceback, que tema o paquete es?

Comment: @SalahAdDin Está usando runserver_plus del paquete django-extensions. Instala django-extensions y ejecuta ./manage.py runserver_plus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recuerda que `create_profile_for_new_user` es una función relacionada al modelo, no es una vista, por lo tanto no tienes acceso al `request`. Tampoco es una clase, por lo que no tienes acceso al `self` como quisieras.

El parámetro `created` no va a funcionar como quisieras ya que lo estás usando en la posición del parámetro incorrecta, el primer parámetro de las funciones que reciben una señal es el modelo que envía la señal (`sender`) y el segundo parámetro es la instancia de ese modelo (`instance`).

El parámetro `instance` es el que contiene el usuario que ha sido creado por lo que lo siguiente es válido:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_profile_for_new_user(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    user = instance # 
    # ...
```

Ni siquiera eso es necesario, podrías hacerlo sin la necesidad de asignar la variable `user`:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_profile_for_new_user(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_medical:
        # ...
    elif instance.is_physiotherapist:
        # ...
    elif instance.is_patient
        # ...
```

Si necesitas asignar los demás campos de tu modelo, también puedes hacerlo aunque pensé que esto ya lo habíamos [resuelto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1362/unsupported-lookup-slug-for-charfield-or-join-on-the-field-not-permitted-usa):

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_profile_for_new_user(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    slug = slugify(instance.first_name)
    User.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk).update(slug=slug)
    # ...
```

### Nota:

Observa que en ninguno de los ejemplos estoy usando el parámetro `created` que habías definido inialmente como parámetro.

Aunque es posible usar el paŕametro `created` del [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save), ten en cuenta que este es el **tercer** parámetro, no el segundo:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_profile_for_new_user(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # ...
```

### Actualización:

El problema que tienes sobre el `IntegrityError` que mencionas en tus comentarios se debe a que cuando te logueas, el sistema está tratando de guardar tu última fecha de logueo y al tratar de hacer esto se llama nuevamente al `post_save` y finalmente a tu función `create_profile_for_new_user`.

La solución es que uses siempre el parámetro `created`:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_profile_for_new_user(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # ...
```

Si no usas esto, la función tratará de guardar nuevamente el perfil y generará un `IntegrityError` ya que el perfil se creó anteriormente cuando  el usuario fue creado inicialmente.

Comment: Cesar, si. Tienes razón. Aunque si utilizo el parametro "created", el slug del post_save no me graba el perfil del usuario.

Comment: De otro lado solo que con respecto a cuando voy a iniciar sesión con un usuario creado el cual automaticamente se le ha creado su perfil de medicaluser con el signal, me pasa lo siguiente: https://cldup.com/DPXcPqDQHY.png

Comment: Es extraño, pues me dice que el id de ese usuario que se esta creando esta duplicado, pero no entiendo un poco lo que sucede, dado que en lla tabla de auth_user este usuario se almacena con id=17 (https://cldup.com/GATSWlmJT6.png)  y en la tabla de userprofile_medicalprofile que es a donde actua el signal del post_save se almacena con id=7 (https://cldup.com/RAxrNt4XY4.png) El atributo user_id es foráneo y por obvias razones coincide por la relacion de OneToOne de ese perfil con el usuario que lo tiene asignado

Comment: Me parece extraño dado que este signal yo lo habia probado con el modelo por defecto de usuarios de django en donde se extendia con una tabla userprofile normalita y funcionaba tambien, y no me notificaba de este error de integridad referencial de duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Comment: @bgarcial como esta tu funcion de logueo? Estas usando alguna predefinida?

Comment: Estoy usando la predefinida 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'. Mi url es este:  url(r'^login/$','django.contrib.auth.views.login', {
                        'authentication_form': CustomAuthenticationForm,},
                        name='login',
    ),

Comment: @bgarcial me gustaría ver desde donde se origina el error, podrías mostrar el traceback completo, tal vez podrías crear otra pregunta creo que no esta relacionada con esta. Solo veo en la imagen que esta tratando de hacer un insert

Comment: Y en forms.py la clase CustomAuthenticationForm le pasa al template el formulario de login. De hecho Django me dice que usar django.contrib.auth.views.login en 1.10 estara "deprecated" (https://cldup.com/vlio0m55W1.png)

Comment: @bgarcial lo que te dice el error no es que la vista estará deprecada, lo que estará deprecado es la forma en la que pasas el parámetro de la vista, al parecer en la version 1.10 de Django ya no podrás pasar la vista como un string: `'django.contrib.auth.views.login'`

Comment: este es el traceback completo http://dpaste.com/3YD4P2V Pero si algo me dices y puedo hacer push a mi repositorio y te lo comparto o hacemos otra pregunta.

Comment: @bgarcial mira mi actualizacion, la solucion es usar siempre el parametro `created`. Me comentas

Comment: si utilizo el parametro created ya no me guarda el perfil del usuario respectivo, es decir no me funciona el signal :(

Comment: @bgarcial es un usuario nuevo? Intenta debuggear el codigo usando `pdb`, solo debería crear el perfil cuando el usuario es creado, para los siguientes casos ya no debería crear nada

Comment: si es un usuario nuevo. Hice el debug con ipdb como me sugeriste, este fue mi análisis, que me gustaría que lo vieras por favor. https://docs.google.com/document/d/10KYInsTUVHFZw7nRkQS0-Z_oT0dHz8SYoP847BucPas/edit Lo que creo que sucede es que el atributo is_medical  nunca llega a ponerse en True y es la condición que tengo para que se grabe la instancia en MedicalProfile. :(

Comment: he estado revisando, y sucede lo que te digo, no se si pensar en sobreescribir el metodo `save` de mi clase User sea una buena alternativa ... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods intentaré por este camino a ver. Muchas gracias por tu valiosa ayuda. :)

Answer (score 2):

En el archivo settings.py tiene que especificar la clase que hereda de AbstractUser en la propiedad [AUTH_USER_MODEL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-user-model) 
Por lo que quedaría

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "app.User"
```

Con ello tomará la instancia de tu clase, no la clase User por default (auth.User)

Comment: Hola Kristian, si en efecto estoy usando un modelo personalizado de usuarios y en mi settings ya lo tengo especificado, es por ello que en el signal el parámetro sender esta así: sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL. Pero lo que realmente debo mirar es como obtener el perfil del usuario que estoy creando para preguntar si van en True el atributo o los atributos de si es usuario tipo paciente, o usuario tipo medico o usuario tipo fisioterapeuta y asi crear su respectivo perfil con sus campos especificos, que todo esto lo haga el signal. :)

Comment: @Kristian quizás te interese [¿Cómo etiquetamos las preguntas de Django?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3210/127)

Answer (score 2):

Finalmente, opté por trabajar sobreescribiendo el método `save()` de la clase `AbstractUser` en lugar de trabajar aplicando el signal `post_save()` a la función `create_profile_for_new_user`, asi que mis modelos `User` `MedicalProfile`, `PatientProfile` y `PhisiotherapystProfile` quedaron así:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_medical = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_physiotherapist = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', null = True, blank = True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = super(User, self).save( *args, **kwargs)

        # Creating and user with medical, patient and physiotherapist profiles
        if self.is_medical and not MedicalProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists()\
                and self.is_patient and not PatientProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists()\
                and self.is_physiotherapist and not PhysiotherapistProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():

            medical_profile=MedicalProfile(user=self).save()
            patient_profile=PatientProfile(user=self).save()
            physiotherapist_profile=PhysiotherapistProfile(user=self).save()
            #profile.save()

        # Creating and user with medical and patient profiles
        elif self.is_medical and not MedicalProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists()\
            and self.is_patient and not PatientProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():

            medical_profile=MedicalProfile(user=self).save()
            patient_profile=PatientProfile(user=self).save()

        # Creating and user with medical and physiotherapist profiles
        elif self.is_medical and not MedicalProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists()\
            and self.is_physiotherapist and not PhysiotherapistProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():

            medical_profile=MedicalProfile(user=self).save()
            physiotherapist_profile=PhysiotherapistProfile(user=self).save()

        # Creating and user with physiotherapist and patient profiles
        elif self.is_physiotherapist and not PhysiotherapistProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists()\
            and self.is_patient and not PatientProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():

            physiotherapist_profile = PhysiotherapistProfile(user=self).save()
            patient_profile = PatientProfile(user=self).save()

        # Creating and user with medical profile
        elif self.is_medical and not MedicalProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():
            profile = MedicalProfile(user=self)
            profile.save()

        # Creating and user with patient profile
        elif self.is_patient and not PatientProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():
            profile = PatientProfile(user=self)
            profile.save()

        # Creating and user with physiotherapist profiles
        elif self.is_physiotherapist and not PhysiotherapistProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():
            profile = PhysiotherapistProfile(user=self)
            profile.save()



    # We get the profiles user according with their type
    def get_medical_profile(self):
        medical_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'medicalprofile'):
            medical_profile=self.medicalprofile
        return medical_profile

    def get_patient_profile(self):
        patient_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'patientprofile'):
            patient_profile = self.patientprofile
        return patient_profile

    def get_physiotherapist_profile(self):
        physiotherapist_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'physiotherapistprofile'):
            physiotherapist_profile = self.physiotherapistprofile
        return physiotherapist_profile

    # We redefine the attributes (create db_table attribute) in class Meta to say to Django
    # that users will save in the same table that the Django default user model
    # https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L343
    class Meta:

        db_table = 'auth_user'

class MedicalProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class PatientProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class PhysiotherapistProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

# Enter the username as slug field
@receiver(post_save, sender = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def post_save_user(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    slug = slugify(instance.username)
    User.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk).update(slug=slug)
```

De esta manera, se puede crear un usuario que tenga todas las combinaciones de roles (medico, paciente, fisioterapeuta) posibles.

De todas maneras se sigue utilizando un signal `post_save()` aplicado en la función `post_save_user()` para ingresar un valor de slug a mi campo `slug` en el modelo `User`. Este valor es basado en el atributo `username`

Muchas gracias por sus constantes orientaciones. :)

Comment: Normalmente es muy desaconcejable editar o modificar el usuario Django, siempre recomiendan hacer un perfil añadido con un enlace Uno a Uno para evitar problemas al modificar el modelo User.
Muy buena respuesta, no olvides marcar la respuesta aceptada.