# Error al querer seleccionar a través de signals (post_save)? en que modelo guardar o no

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

En el siguiente link alguien ha realizado algo similar pero a mi no me funciona: [¿Cómo trabajar con signals (post_save)?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1878/c%C3%B3mo-trabajar-con-signals-post-save?newreg=f73d074859b04886acbd6249f5157940)

He tenido que externder la clase User para poder definir como ULID mi id y ademas agregar un campo llamado is_account, para posteriormente saber que hacer si un usuario es account o un usuario básico.

Tengo  2 Modelos : uno llamado account y otro llamado baseuser, mi idea es que dependiente del valor de un campo del modelo User llamado: is_account, yo pueda hacer el dispacher al modelo BaseUser o Account, no se como evaluar la condición en el dispacher:

aqui mi codigo:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
id = ULIDField(default=default, primary_key=True, editable=False)
is_account = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'auth_user'

class Account(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class BaseUser(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
if created:
    if instance.is_account:
        Account.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        BaseUser.objects.create ( user=instance )
```

He probado, desde la consola de shell de python guardar registros pero siempre me los guarda como usario base, imagino que es por que esta definido is_account=False por defecto en el modelo User

Estos son los comandos que hago en el shell:

```
from myapp.models import User
user=User.objects.create_user('loco@gmail.com', password='232344dssAQDD')
user.is_superuser=False
user.is_staff=False
user.is_account=true
user.save()
```

Mucho supiera agradecer si alguien me ayuda con esto, soy bastante novato pero con ganas de aprender.

Un saludo

Comment: Quizás esto sea importante, posiblemente este haciendo yo algo mal en el shell, cuando ingreso los datos por el panel de admin de django si funciona la condición

Answer (score 0):

Esto debería de funcionar, si cambias el lugar de importación

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Documentacion de django  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model

Answer (score 0):

Hola Chico Gracias por todo, ademas de agregar `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

he realizado el siguiente código en el dispacher:

```
@receiver ( post_save, sender=User )
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs) :
    if created :
        if instance.is_account :
            Account.objects.create ( user=instance )
        else :
            BaseUser.objects.create ( user=instance )



@receiver ( post_save, sender=User )
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created,  **kwargs) :
    if not created :
        if instance.is_account :
            instance.account.save()
        else:
            instance.baseuser.save()
```